# Proving that sum of two measurable functions is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are Lebesgue measurable, we want to show $f+g$ is measurable. So, the hint is to consider the continuous functions $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ given by $h(x) = F(f ,g ) $. If we can show $F$ Is measurable, then Taking $F = f +g $ would solve our problem.

In other words, I want to show that the set $R = \{ (f,g) : F(f,g) > a $ } is lebesgue measurable.. But this set is just a rectangle in the plane. And since $F$ is continuous, then $R$ must be open, and hence a union of open rectangles which are measurable and hence $R$ must be measurable. Is this a correct approach to the problem? Can someone help me to make this formal? thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is a method I used in my analysis class. Note that $f(x) + g(x) < t$ iff $f(x) < t-g(x)$ iff there exists a rational  number $r$ such that $f(x) < r < t-g(x)$.

Therefore $\{x : f(x) + g(x) < t\} = \bigcup_{r\in\Bbb Q} [f^{-1}((-\infty, r)) \cap g^{-1}((-\infty, t-r))]$.

Both the sets being intersected in the union are measurable sets. Hence the set on the left is also measurable, meaning that $f+g$ is measurable.

Comment: Could you please expalain, why we considering rational number 'r'. Can we take real number? and I think t is real?

Comment: We want to use a rational number so that our union is countable. A COUNTABLE union of measurable sets is measurable. I do not believe we can say as much for an uncountable union.

Comment: For an uncountable union we can't even say a thing. Any unmeasurable set of reals is an uncountable union of points, each of which has measure zero.

Comment: This works only when f and g are finite a.e?

Comment: This is a special case of the fact that the output space (here $\mathbb R$) is separable metric space.