# $f,g$ are both measurable on a set $ \Omega $, can $ \{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=g(x) \} $ be non-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f,g$ are both measurable on a set $ \Omega $, can $ \{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=g(x) \} $ be non-measurable?

My attempt: Let $\Omega$ be an open interval in $\Bbb{R}$, then it has a non-measurable subset, say $E$. Let $f=g$ on $E$, and $f>g$ one $\Omega \backslash E$. Is this ok? Thank you!

Comment: Where is the attempt? Where did you define some functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/541118/

Comment: In your attempt, if you want to construct a counterexample, you have to completely define $f$ and $g$.  You can't just say "let".  How do you know there exist *measurable* functions that have this property?  You have to prove it.  (But you're going to have a hard time with that...)

Comment: Also, what is the codomain for $f$ and $g$?  Is it the real line, or an arbitrary measurable space?

Comment: Your question: "Suppose $f,g$ are both measurable on a set $ \Omega $, can $ \{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=g(x) \} $ be non-measurable? "

Your question does not specify the measerable spaces involved. So,
the answer is "YES, it can be non-measurable, depending on the measurable spaces involved".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about real-valued functions, as it seems, then your set is just:

$\{ x \in \Omega: f(x)-g(x)=0\} =h^{-1}(\{0\})$

where $h=f-g$ is a measurable function.

Comment: The question is more or less to prove that f-g is measurable.

Comment: Yes, but my guess is that he knows this, but couldn't make the connection.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, difficult to say from the question (all the charm of the questions with no (real) personal input).

Answer (score 10):

The answer depends on the measurable spaces involved.

**Example 1**: Let $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $f,g$ functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and let us consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$

Then, if $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $h=f-g$ is measurable and we have that $$\{x\in\Omega : f(x)=g(x)\} = \{x\in\Omega : h(x)=0\}$$ is measurable.

**Example 2**: Consider $([0,1], \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is the trivial $\sigma$-álgebra, that is $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, [0,1]\}$. Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $([0,1], \Sigma)$ to $([0,1], \Sigma)$ defined by

$$f(x)=x$$
and
$$g(x)=1-x$$

It is imediate that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions, but 
$$\{x\in\Omega : f(x)=g(x)\} = \{\tfrac{1}{2}\}$$
is NOT measurable.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space with a countable base for open sets.
Let $f, g$ be measurable maps $\Omega \rightarrow X$ with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets of $X$, i.e. $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(U)$ are measurable for all open sets $U$ of $X$.
I claim that the set $A = \{x\in \Omega: f(x) = g(x)\}$ is measurable.

Define a map $h:\Omega \rightarrow X\times X$ by $h(x) = (f(x), g(x))$.
Let $U, V$ be open sets of $X$. Then $h^{-1}(U\times V) = f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$.
This is a measurable set. Since $X$ has a countable base, every open set of $X\times X$ is a countable union of sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open.
Hence $h$ is measurable with respect $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets of $X\times X$.
Since $X$ is Hausdorff, the diagonal $\Delta = \{(x, x): x \in X\}$ is closed.
Hence $A = h^{-1}(\Delta)$ is measurable as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit.** Taking advices from @ByronSchmuland, I modified the proof so that it takes a more direct approach.

Under a mild assumption on the target space, we can prove that $\{f = g\}$ is measurable.

Assume that $X$ is both a topological space and a measurable space that satisfies the following conditions:

- $X$ is a [$T_0$-space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space),
- $X$ is [second countable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) with a countable base $\{ U_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$,
- The $\sigma$-algebra over $X$ contains all the Borel sets.

The first 2 conditions say that if $x, y \in X$, then $x = y$ if and only if for all $i$, either $x, y \in U_i$ or $x, y \notin U_i$. From this, for functions $f, g : \Omega \to X$, we can write

$$
\{ f = g \}
= \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} (\{ f \in U_i \} \cap \{ g \in U_i \}) \cup (\{ f \in X \setminus U_i \} \cap \{ g \in X \setminus U_i \}).
$$

When $f$ and $g$ are measurable, this set is a countable intersection of measurable sets hence is measurable. ////

Notice that these assumptions are automatically satisfied for $X = \Bbb{R}^n$.

For the case $X = \Bbb{R}$, the proof reads out with a slightly more friendly language: for real $x$ and $y$, $x = y$ if and only if for all rational $r \in \Bbb{Q}$, either $x, y > r$ or $x, y \leq r$. So we can write

$$ \{ f = g \} = \bigcap_{r \in \Bbb{Q}} (\{f > r\} \cap \{g > r\}) \cup (\{f \leq r\} \cap \{g \leq r\}), $$

which is measurable. ////

Comment: @BryonSchmuland, I think that the separability condition plays a key role in the proof, and it usually tells us when two *distinct* points are separated. So the condition $f \neq g$ was more natural for me to come up with at first. But I agree that the proof is a detour.