# If $f,g$ are measurable functions, $g \neq 0$ a.e , show $f/g$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $f,g$ are measurable functions, $g \neq 0$ a.e , show $f/g$ is measurable.

I know how to prove $fg$ is measurable. Since $x^2$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$, and $f+g$, $f-g$ are measurable, then $fg=[(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2]/4$ is measurable.

Can I use the above technique to prove the case of $f/g$? What continuous function should I use? Can you provide some hint? Thank you!

Comment: No idea from the answers you received [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1370266), explaining multiple approaches to a *quite related* question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is continuous over $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, so $1/g$ is measurable.