# Deducing measurability of $f$ and $g$ from the measurability of $f+g$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

I was thinking of this - If $f$, $g$ are measurable function then $f+g$ is measurable. (For example, see this post: [Proving that sum of two measurable functions is measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541118/proving-that-sum-of-two-measurable-functions-is-measurable))

But what about the converse that is if $f+g$ is measurable then I think it may not be true that $f$ and $g$ will be measurable.

Is this correct?
Any counterexample we can give?

Comment: For the converse case,also it will be straightforward if we have some information about measurability of any one function $f$ or $g$.
If $f$ is measurable then so is $g$.but how can we deduce f we don't have any information about $f$,$g$?

Comment: Let $f$ be non-measurable and let $g=-f$...

Comment: If $f$ is nonmeasurable, let $g=-f$.

Comment: Then $f+g = 0$ which is measurable and none of $f$,$g$ is measurable ?

Comment: So either $f$ and $g$ both must be measurable or both must be non-measurable.

Comment: @BAYMAX  if they are both unmeasurable then their sum isn't necessarily measurable, $g = -f$ is an example where that can happen

Comment: ok,yeah,if they are both notmeasurable then their sum isn't necessarily measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be non-measurable and let $g=−f$. Then $f+g=0$ which is measurable and none of $f,g$ is measurable.