# Egorov's theorem from Shakarchi-Stein’s book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I was reading the proof of Egorov's theorem and ran into two unclear moments.

1) Why the sets $E_k^n$ are measurable? I was trying in this way: Since $f_j(x)$ are measurable then limit function $f(x)$ is also measurable. Hence $f_j(x)$ and $-f(x)$ are measurable functions. In order $f_j(x)-f(x)$ to be measurable they should be finite a.e. But this condition does not follow the theorem's condition.

2) We know that when we fix $n$ we have $E_k^n\to E$ as $k\to\infty$. Then we can find $k_1$ such that $$m(E-E_{k_1}^n)<\frac{1}{2},$$ and taking $n=1$ we get what we need, namely $m(E-E_{k_1}^1)<\frac{1}{2},$ and we can do this repeatedly and get needed sequence $k_n$. Am I right?

Would be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't understand your issue here. [The sum/difference of two measurable functions is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541118/proving-that-sum-of-two-measurable-functions-is-measurable). Also, if the difference wasn't finite a.e., that would imply at least one of $f_j(x)$ and $f(x)$ are not finite almost everywhere (the union of two measure 0 sets is measure 0 after all).

2) Presumably yes, although it would help to explain what "Corollary 3.3" is.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But let me ask you question: 1) I know the following fact: If $f,g$ are measurable and finite a.e. then $f+g$ is measurable. But in Egorov's theorem $f_j(x)$ and $f(x)$ may not be finite a.e. 2) Corollary 3.3. If $E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3\dots$ and $E=\cup_{k}E_k$ then $m(E)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} m(E_n)$.

Comment: For example we have two functions $f,g:E\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ and we want to show that $f+g$ is also measurable. Since $f$ and $g$ can take infinite values we should be very careful with arithmetic operations.  Even for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ consider $\{f+g>a\}$. Here $f$ and $g$ can take infinite values and I don't know what to do. If they finite then everything is ok. Anyway I would be thankful if you show how to do this in general case.

Comment: @RFZ, If $f$ takes values in $\{-\infty, +\infty\}$ on a set of positive measures, the result is simple false. (As an extreme example, consider $f_n \equiv n$ and $f \equiv +\infty$.) So it is *necessary* to assume that at least $f$ is finite a.e.

Comment: @RFZ, In this example, $f_n$ does not converge pointwise, even at a single point of $E$. (Of course, it depends on how we interpret $a_n \to a$. If this means that $a_n$ converges to $a$, then $a$ is automatically finite, hence $f_n \to f$ a.e. would automatically imply that $f$ is finite a.e. On the other hand, some authors use $a_n \to a$ to denote the fact that $a_n$ has limit $a$, which is often understood in extended-real sense. I adopted the latter interpretation here.)

Comment: @SangchulLee, soory for stupid question, but let me ask it: We have $f_n(x)=n$ and $f(x)=+\infty$ for any $x$ we have that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$. We have the pointwise convergence. Maybe you mean something different by pointwise convergence?

Comment: @RFZ, Perhaps I was not clear enough. I just wanted to point out that pointwise converge in $\mathbb{R}$ is slightly different from one in the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. In my example, $f_n \equiv n$ and $f \equiv \infty$, we have $f_n \not\to f_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ but $f_n \to f$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Now the issue in the latter interpretation is that this need not imply Egorov-type result.

Comment: @SangchulLee, In Egorov type the pointwise convergence means in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @RFZ, I would not say it is a necessity, but at least it must guarantee that $f$ is finite a.e., to even make sense of the notion of uniform convergence on almost-full-measure subsets.