# Equivalence definition of Random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am new to measure theory and recently came across the definition of a Random variable as an equivalence class of almost everywhere equal functions.
More precisely, if
$\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P} \right) $ is a probability space and $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y} : (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{\Theta},\mathcal{G})$ are two measurable functions, define $\mathbf{X}$ to be equivalent to $\mathbf{Y}$ iff $\mathbf{P}(\left\{\omega : \mathbf{X}(\omega) = \mathbf{Y}(\omega)\right\}) = 1$.

- The doubt I am having is that does the above definition implicitly assume the measurability of the set $\left\{\omega : \mathbf{X}(\omega) = \mathbf{Y}(\omega)\right\}$ or can one show that the above set is always measurable ?
  When $\mathbb{\Theta}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra, I saw the proof for the set being measurable [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621791/how-to-prove-the-set-of-the-points-where-two-measrable-funcitons-equal-measurabl) but can it be shown in general?
- In case of former, how does one go about showing the transitivity of the relation?

Comment: The definition of almost everywhere actually means $E = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)\}$ is contained in a set of $P$-measure $0$. $E$ need not be measurable itself, though it is in many cases, e.g. if $\Theta$ is a second-countable normed vector space with $G$ the Borel sigma-algebra on $\Theta$.

Comment: @Mason ahhh i see, thank you. I think if one uses the above definition, then the transitivity of the equivalence relation follows as well just by taking the union of two null sets which contain the above set E for $(\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{Y})$ and $(\mathbf{Y}$, $\mathbf{Z})$. Is that the right argument?

Comment: Yes it comes down to the fact that the union of two null sets is a null set.