# $\{X=Y\}$ is measurable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Given an $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ space and $X, Y$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables, I need to prove $\{\omega\in\Omega|X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\} \in \mathcal{F}$. I begin as follows:

for $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\bigcup\{\{\omega \in\Omega|X(\omega)\leq x\}\cap\{\omega \in\Omega|X(\omega)\geq x\}\cap\{\omega \in \Omega|Y(\omega)\leq x\}\cap\{\omega \in \Omega|Y(\omega)\geq x\}\}$$

The first, second, third and fourth sets belong to $\mathcal{F}$ and so does their intersection. But since $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the union is not countably infinite. How do I overcome this?

Comment: How does $X=Y$ even define a function?

Comment: do you mean that the set $\{ X = Y\}$ is measurable? Because that set is a subset of $\Omega$, it is not a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as (real valued) random variables are.

Comment: I am sorry for being vague. I have made edits to highlight what is required

Comment: @person_who_downvoted, consider leaving a comment for the downvote, so that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that the difference of two measurable functions is also a measurable function. The set $\{\omega\in\Omega|X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\}$ is equal to $(X-Y)^{-1}(\{0\})$ which is measurable by measurability of $X-Y$.

Comment: Thanks but is there be a way to prove it without using the "difference of two measurable functions is also a measurable function" argument?

Comment: The usual way to get around this would be to "pass through the rationals" -- I'm not sure that you'll be able to complete the way you've started because of the difficulty of the uncountability of the reals. The "difference of measurable functions is measurable" fact is *very* useful, not just in this problem -- perhaps it'd be worth proving to solve this? See this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541118/proving-that-sum-of-two-measurable-functions-is-measurable/541174

Comment: @AaronMontgomery thanks, I needed to know that my way would not help in finishing the proof. Now that is clear, I am okay to use the argument in the answer. Thanks again