# Confusions about definition of the sum of two or several random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

### Description of the Questions:

I have some trouble understanding the definition of **the sum of two random variables** and hope someone could help me to get it straight. And my main confusions could be divided into the following questions:

First of all, the usual definition of the sum of two random variables is given by:

---

**Definition: Sum of two random variables**
Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, then define a new random variable $Z(\omega)$ on the same probability space as: $Z(\omega) = X(\omega)+Y(\omega). \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega $

**Notice:** It is necessary to verify that this definition is well defined. i.e. we need to verify that $Z(\omega)$ is indeed a random variable. But we could simply leave it aside since this proof is not required in my question.

---

Now, if we consider the following simple example:

Suppose we have a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \omega_4\}$ & $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and a proper probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. Also, suppose we have two same **discrete** random variable $X_1(\omega)$ and $X_2(\omega)$ defined as follow:

$$X_1(\omega_i) = X_2(\omega_i) = i \quad \forall \omega_i \in \Omega $$
Finally, we could define the sum of these two variables as:

$$Z(\omega) = X_1(\omega) + X_2(\omega) \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$$
But, According to this definition, when $\omega_i$ goes through all the possible value in $\Omega \quad$ i.e.  $i \in \{ 1,2,3,4\}$, $Z(\omega) \in \{ 2,4,6,8\}$

---

I'm fully aware that this result is due to the understanding that restricting $\omega_i$ to be the same event in both $X_1$ and $X_2$

#### Question 1:  From the angle of strictly following the definition, Am I somehow wrong or not in understanding the definition?

But when calculating of probability measure $\mathbb{P}(Z(\omega)=z) = \displaystyle{\sum_{x_{1}}p_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,z-x_2)}$, we could see that $\mathbb{P}(Z(\omega)=3)$ exists and equals to $ \displaystyle\sum_{x_{1}}p_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,3-x_2) = p_{X_1,X_2}(1,2) + p_{X_1,X_2}(2,1)$
I also know that if we allow that $\omega_i$ to be different in $X_1$ and $X_2$, then we should probably consider a 2-dimensional space $\Omega \times \Omega$, i.e. $Z(\delta = (\omega_1,\omega_2)) = X_1(\omega_1) + X_2(\omega_2) \quad \forall \omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega, \delta \in \Omega \times \Omega$

#### Question 2: this definition might work, and also conform to probability calculation, but here $\delta \notin \Omega$, which means $Z(\delta)$ is defined in a different probability space, and thus we need to re-evaluate the well-definedness of such definition, is this idea correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of a random variable it maps to $\mathbb{R}$ so that is where $Z(\omega)$ lands. And yes, when you look at the sum of two random variables you look at a new variable whose domain is a product set of the original $\Omega$. Measurability is defined in a broad way relating image-subsets to domain-subsets. There is no need at all to re-evaluate the well-definedness but rather simply to prove measurability of $Z$. Which you can do like it is done in this post:

[Proving that sum of two measurable functions is measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541118/proving-that-sum-of-two-measurable-functions-is-measurable/541174)

Edit:

In general measurability is defined like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function

In the case of random variables the definition is that X needs to be measurable w.r.t. $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B})$ where $\mathfrak{B}$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra. This means that for any $A \in \mathfrak{B}$ we have that

$X^{-1}(A) \in \mathfrak{F}$

where $\mathfrak{F}$ is the $\sigma$-Algebra of your probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$. A prime reason why we demand this property for random variables is that it allows us to use a Pushforward-Measure on $\mathbb{R}$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

That means we can assign probabilities to random events in $\mathbb{R}$  (e.g. the sum of two throws of a dice) using the probability measure we already have on $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please explain a little more about "Measurability is defined in a broad way relating image-subsets to domain-subsets"?

Comment: what is the definition of ω?

Comment: $\omega \in \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the space where the 'original' probability measure is defined. Or in other words, it is the space where the randomness happens.