# $\{x:f(x)\le g(x)\}$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ be two measurable spaces (the second one being the Borel space). Let $f,g : X\to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable maps, meaning that $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$ and $g^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$ for every $B\in\mathcal{B}$. I was wondering if there are examples when the set $\{x:f(x)\le g(x)\}$ is not $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f>g$ iff $\exists q \in \mathbb{Q}:f>q>g$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}\{x:f(x) > g(x)\}&=\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}\{x:f(x)>q>g(x)\}=\\
&=\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}}(\{x:f(x) >q\}\cap\{x:g(x)<q\}) \in \mathcal{F}
\end{aligned}$$
because both $f$ and $g$ are measurable therefore $\{x:f(x)>g(x)\}^c=\{x:f(x)\leq g(x)\}\in \mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1):

you can see your set as

\begin{eqnarray}
\{x: (f-g)(x)\le 0\}&=&\cup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}_-}\{x : f(x)+g(x) <r\}\\&=&\cup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}_-}\{x : f(x) <r-g(x)\}\\&=&\cup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}_-}\cup_{s\in \mathbb{Q}}(\{x : f(x) \le s\}\cap \{x : s \le r-g(x)\})\\&=&\cup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}_-}\cup_{s\in \mathbb{Q}}(f^{(-1)}(]-\infty,s])\cap (g^{(-1)}(]-\infty,s+r]).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this pre-supposes that $f-g$ is measurable. If OP's question is an intermediate step in proving that $f-g$ is measurable, then this argument would be circular. [But if OP already knows $f-g$ is measurable, then this is fine.]

Comment: I think that they suppose that.

Comment: @angryavian, I wasn't sure about this but I found [a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541174/340973) explaining that $f-g$ is measurable, thank you

Comment: @roi_saumon If you look at the proof that you linked, you will see that it requires you to prove essentially the question that you asked here. So using Hamza's argument is circular. The proof that you linked can actually be used to answer your question here.

Comment: I will change the answer to complet the proof