# Sum of finite-valued measurable functions is again measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions

I'm reading Stein's Real Analysis and I'm looking at P.29, which states
$$\textbf{Property 5}. f+g\text{ is measurable if $f,g$ are measurable and finite-valued.}$$
Now, I understand the proof of the statement, which is well-stated in the book and also in the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541118/proving-that-sum-of-two-measurable-functions-is-measurable). However, I'm intrigued as to why the author ensures the condition that $f$ and $g$ remain finite-valued.

Is it simply because $\infty + (-\infty)$ is not defined?

If so, if we are guaranteed that $f,g\geq 0$, then would it be possible for us to safely say that $f+g$ is again measurable if $f$ and $g$ are? I think there is no problem with the proof if the small "problem" of $\infty+-\infty$ doesn't occur, but I would sure like some reassuring opinions from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT. I've messed around with the proof a bit, and I think my conclusion is that
$$\text{$f+g$ is measurable if $f,g$ are measurable and $f+g$ is well-defined a.e.}$$

Comment: Measurability does not involve measures. So a.e. in your statement should not be there. If $f+g$ is well-defined at all points then it is measurable.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ahh, thanks a lot. I get it now.